# disable/enable a widget using combobox?

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter

is possible to toggle between enable/disable a widget using an option in combobox (optionmenu, dropdown)??
i mean enable it if an option is choosed... with others, disabled...

if yes, how??

i tryed something like this but it didn't worked...

```
op = StringVar(root)
op.set("------")
o0 = OptionMenu(root, op, "opt1", "opt2", "opt3","opt4")

if op.get() is "opt1":
    e_state = 'ENABLED'
else:
    e_state = 'DISABLED'

en9 = Entry(root, width = 30, background = 'white', textvariable = seccion, state=e_state)
```

Comment: `if op.get() is "opt1":` - use `==` instead of `is`. You are only supposed to use `is` if you want to test if two objects are **exactly the same** (as in `somefruit is anotherfruit`) - in this case you only want to test if they are equal (as in `somenumber == 1337`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.op = tk.StringVar(self)
        self.op.set("enable")
        self.om = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.op, "enable","disable", command=self.OnOption)
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, width=30)
        self.om.pack()
        self.entry.pack()

    def OnOption(self, event):
        state = "normal" if self.op.get() == "enable" else "disabled"
        self.entry.configure(state=state)

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```